# Submitting a form in ASP.NET MVC does nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form defined in ASP.NET MVC which upon submit does absolutely nothing. I have a controller method set up to handle it, but for some reason the method never gets called when I submit the form.

The form is defined in C# code using `IHtmlMarkupWriter` derived classes such as `LayoutRow` and `TextBox`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows the user to change their password when it is expired.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ChangeExpiredPassword()
{
    ActionResult actionResult = null;

    try
    {
        ContentViewModel viewModel = new ContentViewModel();

        Form form = new Form();
        form.Method = FormMethod.Post;
        form.Action = "User/ChangeExpiredPassword";

        ValidationSummary summary = new ValidationSummary();
        form.Add(summary);

        GroupBox container = new GroupBox("Change Expired Password");

        LayoutRow rowOldPassword = new LayoutRow();
        var txtOldPassword = new TextBox();
        txtOldPassword.Type = TextBoxType.Password;
        txtOldPassword.Label = "Old Password";
        txtOldPassword.ID = txtOldPassword.Name = "oldPassword";
        rowOldPassword.Add(txtOldPassword);
        container.Add(rowOldPassword);

        LayoutRow rowNewPassword = new LayoutRow();
        var txtNewPassword = new TextBox();
        txtNewPassword.Type = TextBoxType.Password;
        txtNewPassword.Label = "New Password";
        txtNewPassword.ID = txtOldPassword.Name = "oldPassword";
        rowNewPassword.Add(txtNewPassword);
        container.Add(rowNewPassword);

        LayoutRow rowConfirm = new LayoutRow();
        var txtConfirm = new TextBox();
        txtConfirm.Type = TextBoxType.Password;
        txtConfirm.Label = "Confirm New Password";
        txtConfirm.ID = txtConfirm.Name = "confirm";
        rowConfirm.Add(txtConfirm);
        container.Add(rowConfirm);

        LayoutRow row2 = new LayoutRow();

        SubmitButton submit = new SubmitButton();
        row2.Add(submit);

        ResetButton reset = new ResetButton();
        row2.Add(reset);

        container.Add(row2);

        LayoutRow row3 = new LayoutRow();
        container.Add(row3);
        row3.Add(CreateReturnToLoginControl());

        form.Add(container);

        viewModel.ContentControls.Add(form);

        actionResult = View(viewModel);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
        actionResult = Error();
    }

    return actionResult;
}
```

And the handler is set up like so:

```
[HttpPost]
[SupportedBehaviors(BehaviorName.ChangeMyPassword)]
public ActionResult ChangeExpiredPassword(ChangeMyPasswordModel model)
{
    ActionResult actionResult = null;
    JsonResponse response = null;

    try
    {
        IBehaviorProvider<IChangeMyPasswordModel> provider = new ChangeMyPasswordBehaviorProvider();
        var result = provider.Handle(model);

        string xml = String.Format("<Data><OldPassword>{0}</OldPassword><NewPassword>{1}</NewPassword></Data>", model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
        LogSecurityEvent(SecurityLogType.InvokedChangeMyPassword);

        response = new JsonResponse(result.Successful, result.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response = new JsonResponse(false, ex.Message);
    }

    actionResult = Json(response);

    return actionResult;
}
```

The first method gets called when I navigate to the `ChangeExpiredPassword` action, but when I submit the form, nothing happens; the second method is not called. What could be happening here? How can I get the POST method to be called?

Comment: How are you rendering the form? Please include your view file.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "Does Nothing".  Does the original page just stay there, or does something else happen?  Have you looked at what happens on the wire with a tool like Fiddler?  Do you see the POST happening using Fiddler or some other tool?  If you do the POST manually with a tool like Postman, does something happen?

Answer (score 0):

I needed a slash before the name of my action:

```
form.Action = "/User/ChangeExpiredPassword";
```

not

```
form.Action = "User/ChangeExpiredPassword";
```